# Detect iDevices and exchange information

Tags: iphone, networking, bonjour

I would like to develop an application on iPhone, iPod Touch and iPad which will be able to:

- run in backgroup
- Detecte other iDevices which are close to the iPhone
- Exchange information with these devices

I do not know if it is better to use wifi or bluetooth in that case but what I would like to achieve is to have something which does not require configuraion (bonjour?)

Thanks in advance for your ideas and pointers.

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

The Bump API is great for this: http://bu.mp/api

**But I suggest you to take a look at this tutorial:**
http://www.devx.com/wireless/Article/43502/